# Lodash utils a la `mapArrayToObj` and its reverse?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I bunch of utility function I keep recreating across projects look like this:

```
export function objectToArray(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
}

export function mapArrayToObj(arr) {
  return addArrayToObj({}, arr);
}

export function addArrayToObj(obj, arr) {
  arr.forEach((elem) => obj[elem._id] = elem); // '_id' would be a param
  return obj;
}

export function patchExisting(existingEntitiesDict, newEntitiesDict) {
  return Object.assign(existingEntitiesDict, newEntitiesDict);
}
```

This is essentially overlapping somewhat with [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr), but I would like to know if there is some functionality in `lodash` that I can use instead of recreating these mapping functions from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the lodash (or ES6) equivalents

`objectToArray(obj)` -> lodash [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#values) or ES6 [`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

`mapArrayToObj(arr)` -> lodash [`_.keyBy(arr, 'id')`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy)

`addArrayToObj(obj, arr)` -> lodash [`_.assign(obj, _.keyBy(arr, 'id'))`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign)

`patchExisting(existingEntitiesDict, newEntitiesDict)` -> lodash's `_.assign(existingEntitiesDict, newEntitiesDict)`

Comment: Perfect. Knew there was something like this.